# Disable JavaScript temporarily in CefSharp

Tags: c#, javascript, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have written a little program with embedded CefSharp.WebView that harvests data from several web sites by parsing their source code and extracting the relevant data, but a couple of them don't have their data in source code, but load the data via JavaScript a bit later. 
But fortunately these sites do check if JavaScript is enabled and do provide the data in source code when JavaScript is disabled.

So I'd like to have JS enabled by default and only temporarily disable JS before loading one of these odd pages.

Is there a way to achive this in CefSharp under C#?

Originally I intended to use the IE WebBrowser control but this definitely does only use the global Internet settings and there is no way to disable JS temporarily there and I don't want to disable JS on my system for good.

Comment: In CEF you can pass the "javascript_disabled" option to CreateBrowser/CreateBrowserSync() functions.

Comment: If you're using CEF3 see this post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cefsharp/IWjMe9JsAFU/rxSlFrbHFMoJ In the header option is here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/CefSharp3/CefSharp/BrowserSettings.h#L148